# Extend depth of .htaccess to all subfolders and their children

Tags: php, apache, htaccess

I need to be able to use .htaccess in all subfolders for full depth. E.g. I have .htaccess in `public_html` folder:

```
\public_html\.htaccess
```

How I make it to work for the folder `small` as well?

```
\public_html\home\images\red\thumbs\small\
```

It only enforces up to home directory not more.

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://google.com
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 11.22.33.44



Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: htaccess rules *do* inherit to sub-directories. [See here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#what) If you're not seeing that behavior, it's more likely a problem with the rules themselves, and you need to provide an example.

Comment: @Su' Can you post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Apache? Subdirectories are supposed to inherit .htaccess by default under Apache.

Check your `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file. It could be that you have a `<Directory>` directive that is keeping your .htaccess from being applied to subdirectories, like it should by default.

Answer (score 3):

I was having this trouble as well.

And it turned out the solution is quite simple:

In your "main" .htaccess under /your_root/, add the following lines:

`RewriteBase /your_root/`

`RewriteOptions InheritDown`

Comment: This is good! Only found the opposite solution so far (setting the inheritance from within the deeper level .htaccess). Works with apache 2.4.8 and later.

Comment: Just brilliant.